# When creating transaction with fake-valid-nonce in test, the transaction result shows me the message: "Gateway Rejected: duplicate”

Tags: testing, transactions, braintree

There is a problem when I trying to create a transaction with `fake-valid-nonce` in my test.

Here’s the code about create transaction:

```
const createTransaction = (price, nonceFromTheClient, customerBrainTreeId) => {
  const transactionToken = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gateway.transaction.sale(
      {
        amount: price,
        customerId: customerBrainTreeId,
        paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,
        options: {
          submitForSettlement: true
        }
      },
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          logger.error(`create transaction error: ${error}`);
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      });
  });

  return transactionToken;
};
```

And here is the code about test:

```
it(‘**************************', () => {
  return PaymentService.createTransaction("104.0", 'fake-valid-nonce', null)
    .then(result => {
      expect(result.success).to.be.true;
      expect(result.transaction.status).to.be.equals('submitted_for_settlement');
      expect(result.transaction.type).to.be.equals('sale');
    });
});
```

When I run the test for the first time, this test will pass. But, if I run this test multiple times, this test will not pass, and the transaction result shows me the message: **"Gateway Rejected: duplicate”**.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I have already found the solution under the help of braintree support team:

The error  `Gateway Rejected: duplicate` is triggered not because you use a test nonce value but because you have the Duplicate Transaction Checking option enabled in your Sandbox account (it is enabled by default). Duplicate transaction checking prevents transaction requests from accidentally processing more than once. This can happen if a customer refreshes your checkout page or clicks a button that issues a new API request. In order to disable or configure that option I invite you to log into your Braintree Control Panel and go to **Settings > Processing > Edit or Disable under Duplicate Transaction Settings**.

Comment: You should NOT turn this setting off. The sandbox only blocks these if you are submitting the payment twice (usually by mistake). You should check your code to make sure this isn't happening.